# cronjob at resume from suspend

Tags: cron, suspend, scheduling, reboot, hibernate

using linux. I know you can do an `@reboot` cronjob. I want to do an equivalent thing but instead of running at reboot, running after my computer awakens from suspend. Is that possible?

Comment: What is the OS? Mac OS X has hooks for this (or otherwise fires shield window notifications); other OS may or may not have such a hook.

Comment: linux. added that to original question for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your distro and/or your destop enviroment, without this info i cant tel much, only that each dispo/desktop enviroment handle it on other ways.

like you see the way for ubuntu is nearly complete different how debian handle this.

Ubuntu solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup

Debian solution http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=53442

depending on which distro or desktop enviroment you use i recommand to have the first look in your runlevels.